# Why is the H1 tag not being rendered before the execution of a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning Javascript and I am doing a small exercise in which I try to guess a random number within 5 attempts.

I have defined a small HTML file in which I load the Javascript file at the end of the `<body>` tag.

```js
//datos del programa
var numCorrect = parseInt(Math.random() * 100); //valor generado aleatoriamente
console.log(numCorrect);
var numAdivinado;
var guesses = [];
var limit = 5;

//mostrando caja de texto al usuario
while ( limit > 0) {
   limit--;
   numAdivinado = parseInt(window.prompt("Ingrese un número"));

   if (valArray(numAdivinado) == true) {
       limit++;
   }

   document.write("Los numeros hasta ahora ingresados son: " + guesses.toString() + "\n");

   if (numAdivinado == numCorrect) {
       document.write("El numero ingresado coincide con el aleatorio");
       break;
   } else {
       window.alert("Error! - Le quedan " + limit + " intentos");
   }

   if(limit == 0) {
       document.write("Perdio! - El número correcto era: " + numCorrect);
   }

}

//función que valida el array
function valArray(numb) {
   if (guesses.length > 0) {
       for(var i = 0; i<guesses.length; i++) {
           if(numb == guesses[i]) {
               window.alert("El numero ya fue elegido, debe usar otro - no perdera una portunidad");
               return true;
           }
       }
       guesses[guesses.length] = numb;
       return false;
   } else {
       guesses[0] = numb;
       return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="es">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Guessing Game</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>Guessing Game</h1>

       <script src="game.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I load the page for the first time the H1 tag is rendered and then the pop-up window that requests a number appears, which starts the execution of the application. At the end of the execution of the application and show the results, **I use the <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> keys to reload the page and run the application again but I do not understand why the H1 tag is not rendered again before displaying the pop-up window.** Simply pop up the popup window directly and after all the attempts are made, everything is rendered including the H1 tag.

So far I've read that when I add the `<script>` tag to the end of the body, I should at least allow the `<H1>` tag to be rendered at the first instance with the title and then execute all the JS logic.

Could you explain to me why this is not happening? or how the HTML rendering actually works in this example.

Comment: Avoid using `document.write`. Use DOM properties / methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt get rendered because you are in a while loop which doesnt leave time for the rendering if you define a function instead and call it with `setTimeout(functionName,1)` at the end it will work this leaves 1 millisecond etween each call where the rendering can happen example :

```
         limit =5;
         function parseNumber(currentLimit);
           numAdivinado = parseInt(window.prompt("Ingrese un número"));

           if (valArray(numAdivinado) == true) {
               limit++;
           }

           document.write("Los numeros hasta ahora ingresados son: " + guesses.toString() + "\n");

           if (numAdivinado == numCorrect) {
               document.write("El numero ingresado coincide con el aleatorio");
               break;
           } else {
               window.alert("Error! - Le quedan " + limit + " intentos");
           }

           if(limit == 0) {
               document.write("Perdio! - El número correcto era: " + numCorrect);
           }
           if(currentLimit<limit ){
               //functino to call , timeout, ...parameters
               setTimeout(parseNumber,1,currentLimit-1)
           }
        }
        parseNumber(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your javascript with:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here
});
```

this will ensure that your DOM has loaded before your script executes.

---

Also, you should not use document.write as @Alex Kudryashev mentioned. You should use document fragments using document.createElement, and appendChild:

```
let paragraph = document.createElement('p');
paragraph.innerText = "whatever I need to load or say";

// you can use the body, a div, or whatever element you want to append to
myElement.appendChild(paragraph);
```

[jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/document-fragment-vs-innerhtml-vs-looped-appendchild)
[CoderWall Article](https://coderwall.com/p/o9ws2g/why-you-should-always-append-dom-elements-using-documentfragments)

Comment: How does this answers the question? OP is asking **why** is something happening.

Comment: @Camilo it does answer his question, I clearly state that if you put in the `DOMContentLoaded` the JavaScript will run after. No reason to downvote.

Comment: OP is asking why this happens, not how to fix it.

Comment: By telling the OP that the DOM needs to load before the script executes IS telling him why. You're wrong here.